# Meteor Deny certain Collection Fields

Tags: meteor

In Meteor, how can I deny a certain field from being updated? I want all fields to be allowed except for one field.

For example...

```
COLLECTION.deny({
    update: function(userId, docs, fields, modifier) {
        return _.contains( fields, ['DENY_THIS_FIELD'])
    }
})
```

In that code, I'm trying to see if the update query contained "DENY_THIS_FIELD", if so I'm trying to deny this query.

That didn't work. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```js
return _.contains(fields, 'DENY_THIS_FIELD');
```

Your original code was looking for the array `['DENY_THIS_FIELD']` inside of `fields`. However, `fields` is an array of strings, not an array of arrays.